# Comprehensive question quality blocks now enabled here

Tags: discussion, post-ban

See: [Comprehensive question quality blocks now enabled everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291142/21960)

Previously, users whose posts here were generally not well received may have received warnings about them, but were never in danger of being throttled or blocked from posting. That is no longer true. These quality blocks are now live on all Stack Exchange sites, including this one.

In practice, I don't think it will have much impact. We have more than our fair share of "drive by" askers; people who drop in, ask one question, and disappear.

One thing I'd like to emphasize from [Shog9's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291142/21960):

> Quality blocks are based on each community's rating of questions and answers, therefore the most useful things you can do are:
>
> > - if you see a great, thoughtfully asked, well researched question, vote it up — please! Great questions are an art!
> > - if you see an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended question that you feel was asked in bad faith … vote it down.
> > - anything in between that’s salvageable, edit it!
>
> Don't worry about the exact details of the algorithm used for blocking - in general, it's fairly conservative as far as who or what gets blocked. On the majority of sites, this will affect few if any users in the near future. Most users will encounter [rolling rate-limits](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited) and [warnings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow/231118#231118) long before they encounter this block.
>
> As always, vote your conscience and encourage new members to participate constructively.

The quality checks/blocks can't work if people aren't voting. I can't tell you how discouraging it is to find an egregiously bad post and that no one has downvoted it.

Anyway, questions/concerns about the universal quality question blocks should be posted as an answer on [the original question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291142/21960).

Comment: Good call in sharing this!